# How can I assemble a 64-bit assembly language program in Cygwin under Windows7?

Tags: windows, assembly, cygwin, x86-64, nasm

I want to do assembly programming in Linux using NASM ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAy4FGHDx1I)). But, I want to avoid installing Linux on my machine. Rather, I have a 64-bit Win7 machine in which Cygwin is installed.

The following is my test program:

```
section     .data
            text1   db      "What is your name?"
            text2   db      "Hello "

section     .bss
            name    resb    30

section     .text
            global  start

start:
            ; display the prompt
            mov rax, 1      ; specify std out
            mov rdi, 1      ; specify write opeartion
            mov rsi, text1  ; load the address of the variable
            mov rdx, 19     ; write sizeof(text1) == 19 bytes
            syscall         ; tell the processor to accomplish the task

            ; take input from KB
            mov rax, 0      ; specify std in
            mov rdi, 0      ; specify read operation
            mov rsi, name   ; load the address of the variable
            mov rdx, 30     ; read sizeof(name) == 30 bytes
            syscall         ; tell the processor to accomplish the task

            ; display "Hello "
            mov rax, 1      ; specify std out
            mov rdi, 1      ; specify write opeartion
            mov rsi, text2  ; load the address of the variable
            mov rdx, 7      ; write sizeof(text2) == 7 bytes
            syscall         ; tell the processor to accomplish the task

            ; display 'name'
            mov rax, 1      ; specify std out
            mov rdi, 1      ; specify write opeartion
            mov rsi, name   ; load the address of the variable
            mov rdx, 30     ; write sizeof(name) == 30 bytes
            syscall         ; tell the processor to accomplish the task

            ; terminate program
            mov rax, 60     ; specify program termination
            mov rdi, 0      ; return without error
            syscall
```

The following is my assembly command and output:

```
Acer@Acer-PC ~
$ nasm -f elf64 name_io.asm -o name_io.o

Acer@Acer-PC ~
$ ld name_io.o -o name_io.exe

Acer@Acer-PC ~
$ ./name_io
Illegal instruction

Acer@Acer-PC ~
$
```

The source code is being assembled, but it is not executing.

What can I do to properly assemble and run a Linux-assembly program in Cygwin+Windows?

Comment: You created a 64 bit program all right, but the code you used is for linux. That will not work on windows. `cygwin` does not emulate `syscall`. You need to use the POSIX functions instead.

Comment: Or use Windows Subsystem for Linux to get a Windows kernel layer that supports x86-64 Linux system calls.  IDK if you can install a bare-bones version of this that provides just the kernel side without much or any user-space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly Syscalls in 64-bit Windows](//stackoverflow.com/q/49947915) but it doesn't fit perfectly, the answer doesn't directly address cygwin only emulating a POSIX environment via library function calls, definitely not *Linux* system calls.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have WSL.

Comment: You could install a Linux VM, e.g. in VirtualBox (or VMWare or Parallels). That is quite easy and they often come pre-packaged. Just download and start with VirtualBox.